# Unconventional Unpivot and Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, reportbuilder3.0

I have looked around and I have not found anything exactly like this so I thought it might be helpful to everyone to ask. The long story short is that I have a column with a year followed by columns of months which contain numbers:

```
[year] | [month1] | [month2]
1999       4          2
```

Basically, I want to unpivot the month so I can name it something normal like "March" or "03" while keeping the year to the left and the number to the right:

```
[year] | [month] | [numbers]
1999      month1      4
1999      month2      2
```

Finally, I want to take that into Report Builder but I will leave that for later. Here is a copy of the data with which I am working.

I really hope this is descriptive enough because this have been bugging me for a couple of days.

```
CSYEAR  CSOR01  CSOR02  CSOR03  CSOR04  CSOR05  CSOR06  CSOR07  CSOR08  CSOR09  CSOR10  CSOR11  CSOR12
1999        2       0       0       0       1       2       0       3       1       4       0       3
2000        4       1       3       3       2       2       2       2       4       1       4       4

1999    CSOR01  2                                       
1999    CSOR02  0                                       
1999    CSOR03  0                                       
1999    CSOR04  0                                       
1999    CSOR05  1                                       
1999    CSOR06  2                                       
1999    CSOR07  0                                       
1999    CSOR08  3                                       
1999    CSOR09  1                                       
1999    CSOR10  4                                       
1999    CSOR11  0                                       
1999    CSOR12  3                                       
2000    CSOR01  4                                       
2000    CSOR02  1                                       
2000    CSOR03  3                                       
2000    CSOR04  3                                       
2000    CSOR05  2                                       
2000    CSOR06  2                                       
2000    CSOR07  2                                       
2000    CSOR08  2                                       
2000    CSOR09  4                                       
2000    CSOR10  1                                       
2000    CSOR11  4                                       
2000    CSOR12  4
```

Thank you all for any help you can recommend.

Comment: How is this different than a standard UNPIVOT?

Comment: The SELECT portion confused me. I was unaware I could keep certain columns and basically unpivot "out to the right" (hope that makes sense. I thought it was a pivot or unpivot everything in the table, in which I would have just been flipping things back and forth with no progress. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CSYEAR, MONTH, NUMBER
FROM myTable
UNPIVOT
(
  NUMBER
  for MONTH in (CSOR01, CSOR02, CSOR03, CSOR04, CSOR05, CSOR06, CSOR07, CSOR08, CSOR09, CSOR10, CSOR11, CSOR12)
) u;
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e7df/3)

Comment: Umm. Wow. Seriously, I have working on this for over a day and never saw that pattern in the SELECT area. That was EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a high enough reputation score to comment on @PinnyM's excellent answer, but if you were looking for the name of the month you could modify it to do the following:

```
SELECT
  CSYEAR, 
  MONTH,
  DATENAME(Month, CAST(RIGHT(MONTH,2) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01/1900'), 
  NUMBER
FROM myTable
UNPIVOT
(
  NUMBER
  for MONTH in (CSOR01, CSOR02, CSOR03, CSOR04, CSOR05, CSOR06, CSOR07, CSOR08, CSOR09, CSOR10, CSOR11, CSOR12)
) u;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e7df/5)

Comment: This is really interesting and I greatly appreciate what you have written here. My next step is the conversion portion so this really puts me in the right direction. Thank you so much!